# Tables with foreign key constraints not getting imported in symfony

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine, foreign-keys, innodb

I tried to import tables from InnoDB using

```
php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import --force AppBundle xml

php bin/console doctrine:mapping:convert annotation ./src
```

All those tables that has a foreign key are not getting imported. The rest are getting imported. How to import the tables with the foreign key constraint?

Comment: Are your imports being done in the proper order? Tables created first then FK constraints added after. Doctrine documentation even says it cannot fully build the database for you with imports and some manual work will be needed. http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/tools.html#reverse-engineering

Comment: Oh, I see. Thankyou.